# How to get the file names present in a particular location mentioned

Tags: java

Can any one tell me how can I get the file names present in the particular location say

`E:/abc_RESPONSE/Response_`.

I tried to use The

`java.io.File.getName()`

method which returns the last name of the pathname's name sequence, that means the name of the file or directory denoted by this abstract path name is returned. But I need all the file names present in that particular location.

```
String name = (String)(new File("E:/abc_RESPONSE/Response_").getName());
```

I am using the above code please help to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
 public void listFiles(String directoryName){

        File directory = new File(directoryName);

        //get all the files from a directory

        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

        for (File file : fList){

           if (file.isFile()){

             System.out.println(file.getName());

           }

        }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String[] names = new File("E:/abc_RESPONSE/Response_").list();
```